# std::vector<std::tuple in for - cannot get values

Tags: c++

with tuple i have this code

```
for (std::vector<std::tuple<uint32, std::string, uint32> >::const_iterator ixn = messages.begin(); ixn != messages.end(); ++ixn)
{
    if (std::get<0>(ixn) == user->getID() && std::get<1>(ixn) == msg && std::get<2>(itr) > time)
    {
         //some doin
    }
}
```

and it sayin

```
no matching function for call to ‘get(std::vector<std::tuple<long unsigned...
```

Comment: `std::get<0>(*ixn)` you forgot to dereference the iterator.

Comment: @Borgleader No, it not works... Event with *

Comment: Your last comparison uses `itr` and not `ixn`, is that on purpose?

Comment: no, its only my bad while copying there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dereference your iterator using (*ixn). Also your last iterator is called `itr` instead of `ixn`.

```
for (std::vector<std::tuple<uint32, std::string, uint32> >::const_iterator ixn = messages.begin(); ixn != messages.end(); ++ixn)
{
    if (std::get<0>(*ixn) == user->getID() && std::get<1>(*ixn) == msg && std::get<2>(*ixn) > time)
    {
         //some doin
    }
}
```

Comment: (std::get<0>(*ixn) == user->getID() && std::get<1>(*ixn) == msg && std::get<2>(*ixn) > time )

this i have now... but it wont work

Comment: The error is still the same ?

Comment: ah, my bad... Yes, the error isnt the same. :) It now works. Thank u guys. :)

Comment: @JeleanThomas Please accept an answer if it solved your question instead of writing a thank you comment.